# How to do header auth request for only in domain people?

Tags: php, laravel

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
if (!isset($headers['Authorization'])){
  header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
  header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM');
  exit;
}
```

How to make this request only for those in the domain? And do not touch those who are not in the domain and do not have a login? Now an alert window pops up that asks the login password for those who are not in the domain I would like to avoid this

Comment: Are you using `laravel`?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the domain"?

Comment: my site created on laravel and using ldap auth! 2) in the domain it's corparate computer when i on computer i use login and password for enter, this is my Active Directory account, and auth on my site also ldap using this login for auth. When i use corporate computer with ntlm on my site i can catch my ad login from computer on site and use it for auto authorization ( ntlm sso)